# Checking sizes on a product page

Tags: e-commerce, conversion-rate, product-design

Is it best to have product sizes in a drop down box or as buttons, someone said to me buttons because it's one less click.

So examples of buttons would be on the product pages of this site - www.costumecrowd.co.uk (my site). I guess another question would be if buttons are indeed better maybe a label should be added near the element explaining what that the area is as S, M, L - doesn't exactly say.

Answer (score 3):

I think buttons are better as well because it gives the user a full understanding of what sizes are available and how the garment is sized just at a glance. For example, a dress can be sized with letters (XS, S, M...) or numbers (00, 0, 2, 4), and all sizes might not be offered (XS, 00). Even if your sizing is generally consistent, it's still helpful to shoppers who are hopping from e-commerce to e-commerce site where sizes and selections vary.

For example, J. Crew employs this well, in my opinion:

[image: Sizes]

Comment: I would have to agree with @Kristin the button is definitely not only more convenient for the user but also has a more sleek look to it. They can customize everything they want about their order in simple clicks and nothing more. The example above of J. Crew is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

I agree about having boxes/buttons, anyway already exploded in page.

But there are several cases which would push call to actions way too far down.

Example Nike pages for shoes.

[image]